# Undo and Redo in an Tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, text, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Is there a way to add *undo* and *redo* capabilities in Tkinter `Entry` widgets or must I use single line `Text` widgets for this type of functionality?

If the latter, are there any tips I should follow when configuring a `Text` widget to act as an `Entry` widget?

Some features that might need tweaking include trapping the `Return` `KeyPress`, converting tab keypresses into a request to change focus, and removing newlines from text being pasted from the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: these are just thoughts that come into my mind on how to implement it.

```
class History(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = ['']
        self.i = 0

    def next(self):
        if self.i == len(self.l):
            return None
        self.i += 1
        return self.l[self.i]

    def prev(self):
        if self.i == 0:
            return None
        self.i -= 1
        return self.l[self.i]

    def add(self, s):
        del self.l[self.i+1:]
        self.l.append(s)
        self.i += 1

    def current(self):
        return self.l[self.i]
```

Run a thread that every X seconds (0.5?) save the state of the entry:

```
history = History()
...
history.add(stringval.get())
```

You can also set up events that save the Entry's status too, such as the pressure of `Return`.

```
prev = history.prev()
if prev is not None:
    stringvar.set(prev)
```

or

```
next = history.next()
if next is not None:
    stringvar.set(next)
```

Beware to set locks as needed.

Comment: using a thread here is completely unnecessary. The widget can easily notify you when it is changed.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: not really, this is just a different approach at the problem, one of many solutions.

Comment: @MG: Good plan: Trap every change to a widget, store the total value in a history list, on undo, move the history pointer back one level and grab its value. On redo, move the history pointer forward one level and grab its value. When storing user changes, clear the redo history after every user change. I'm not a fan of the thread monitoring - what I need is the equivalent of an on-value-change event (or possibly trace_var()) so that I can track exact changes. I posted a question about the existence of such an event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165164

Comment: @Malcom: I know that it isn't a good solution, but as I said was just a thought because at first I didn't liked to trace every variable change, but in a event loop you can set a time-out. By the way it has to be just a trace on how implement the `History`, the most interesting part. Look at changes to `History` class, extending `list` is not a good idea.

Comment: @MG: Your thought process helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check the Tkinter Custom Entry. I have added Cut, Copy, Paste context menu, and undo redo functions.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *


class CEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.changes = [""]
        self.steps = int()

        self.context_menu = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Paste")

        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        self.bind("<Control-z>", self.undo)
        self.bind("<Control-y>", self.redo)

        self.bind("<Key>", self.add_changes)

    def popup(self, event):
        self.context_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        self.context_menu.entryconfigure("Cut", command=lambda: self.event_generate("<<Cut>>"))
        self.context_menu.entryconfigure("Copy", command=lambda: self.event_generate("<<Copy>>"))
        self.context_menu.entryconfigure("Paste", command=lambda: self.event_generate("<<Paste>>"))

    def undo(self, event=None):
        if self.steps != 0:
            self.steps -= 1
            self.delete(0, END)
            self.insert(END, self.changes[self.steps])

    def redo(self, event=None):
        if self.steps < len(self.changes):
            self.delete(0, END)
            self.insert(END, self.changes[self.steps])
            self.steps += 1

    def add_changes(self, event=None):
        if self.get() != self.changes[-1]:
            self.changes.append(self.get())
            self.steps += 1
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. Using thread is kind of over-engineer in this case...

Answer (score 2):

Update on using this method for Undo/Redo:

I am creating a GUI with lot of frames and each contains at least ten or more 'entry' widgets. 
I used the History class and created one history object for each entry field that I had. I was able to store all entry widgets values in a list as done here. 
I am using 'trace' method attached to each entry widget which will call 'add' function of History class and store each changes. In this way, I was able to do it without running any thread separately. 
But the biggest drawback of doing this is, we cannot do multiple undos/redos with this method.

Issue: 
When I trace each and every change of the entry widget and add that to the list, it also 'traces' the change that happens when we 'undo/redo' which means we cannot go more one step back. once u do a undo, it is a change that will be traced and hence the 'undo' value will be added to the list at the end. Hence this is not the right method.

Solution:
Perfect way to do this is by creating two stacks for each entry widget. One for 'Undo' and one for 'redo'. When ever there is a change in entry, push that value into the undo stack. When user presses undo, pop the last stored value from the undo stack and importantly push this one to the 'redo stack'. hence, when the user presses redo, pop the last value from redo stack.

Comment: I used this exact method on a chess app I wrote a while ago, and it works great! It keeps things nice and simple, and organized. No trying to remember what index of the undo stack you were at, and easy to clear the redo stack. +1

Answer (score 1):

Based on Evgeny's answer with a custom `Entry`, but added a tkinter `StringVar` with a trace to the widget to more accurately track when changes are made to its contents (not just when any Key is pressed, which seemed to add empty Undo/Redo items to the stack). Also added a max depth using a Python deque.

If we're changing the contents of the Entry via code rather than keyboard input, we can temporarily disable the trace (e.g. see in the `undo` method below).

**Code:**

```
class CEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master=master, **kw)
        self._undo_stack = deque(maxlen=100)
        self._redo_stack = deque(maxlen=100)
        self.bind("<Control-z>", self.undo)
        self.bind("<Control-y>", self.redo)
        # traces whenever the Entry's contents are changed
        self.tkvar = tk.StringVar()
        self.config(textvariable=self.tkvar)
        self.trace_id = self.tkvar.trace("w", self.on_changes)
        self.reset_undo_stacks()
        # USE THESE TO TURN TRACE OFF THEN BACK ON AGAIN
        # self.tkvar.trace_vdelete("w", self.trace_id)
        # self.trace_id = self.tkvar.trace("w", self.on_changes)

    def undo(self, event=None):  # noqa
        if len(self._undo_stack) <= 1:
            return
        content = self._undo_stack.pop()
        self._redo_stack.append(content)
        content = self._undo_stack[-1]
        self.tkvar.trace_vdelete("w", self.trace_id)
        self.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.insert(0, content)
        self.trace_id = self.tkvar.trace("w", self.on_changes)

    def redo(self, event=None):  # noqa
        if not self._redo_stack:
            return
        content = self._redo_stack.pop()
        self._undo_stack.append(content)
        self.tkvar.trace_vdelete("w", self.trace_id)
        self.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.insert(0, content)
        self.trace_id = self.tkvar.trace("w", self.on_changes)

    def on_changes(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):  # noqa
        self._undo_stack.append(self.tkvar.get())
        self._redo_stack.clear()

    def reset_undo_stacks(self):
        self._undo_stack.clear()
        self._redo_stack.clear()
        self._undo_stack.append(self.tkvar.get())
```