# On-value-change type of event for widgets or use .trace_variable() technique?

Tags: python, events, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

Is there an on-value-change type of event for data input widgets like Entry, Text, Spinner, Checkbutton, Radiobutton? By on-value-change, I mean the ability to detect when the value of a widget has changed due to keyboard input or cut/delete/paste (and Text edit_undo/edit_redo) activity? I see no such event described in the Tkinter event documentation [1].

Is the proper technique to link Tkinter variables to widget values I want to monitor and use these variables' .trace_variable( 'w', ... ) methods to bind to value changes? This seems like the right approach, but I haven't seen a lot of trace_variable() use in the Tkinter application source code that I've studied ... leading me to be cautious about using this approach.

[1] http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/events.html

Comment: I think Bryan Oakley's response to the following post [1] answers my question. Quote: "Binding to keypress isn't the right solution. It won't, for example, handle the case where you paste with the mouse. Also, binding to a keypress will under default circumstances fire before the widget is updated since the update happens in the class bindings which fire after the widget-specific bindings. Textvariables and traces are the way to go."  [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524031/python-tkinter-connect-variable-to-entry-widget

Comment: I believe the following link confirms Bryan's advice: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different widgets call for different solutions. For example, check buttons and radio buttons have a command option, and with an entry widget you can use the built-in validation features.

For all the widgets that can be tied to a variable, doing a variable trace is a common solution. The text widget is one exception since you can't associate it with a variable without a lot of effort.

In the tcl/tk world I associate all my widgets to a single array (tcl's name for a hash map / dictionary) and then put a single trace on the array. Unfortunately tkinter doesn't directly support tcl arrays. However, support is somewhat easy to hack in. For more information see my response to this question: [How to run a code whenever a Tkinter widget value changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876229/how-to-run-a-code-whenever-a-tkinter-widget-value-changes/3883495#3883495)

Comment: Your 2 examples - the one I originally cited and the advanced tcl array example - answered my question. Thank you very much for your help in these forums.